# Adding Event Listener is not working in Chrome for audio tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-audio

I am developing a music application for playing songs on the browser using HTML5. After creating playlists I wanted to play the songs one by one. So I am using the `eventListener` to get the work done. My code is given below :

```
document.getElementById('myplayer').addEventListener('ended',function() {
    alert("HI");  
    });
```

Here `myplayer` is the id of the audio tag so when one song is completed I wanted to put the next song on the player. But this method is not getting triggered as I am unable to see the alert on the screen when the song ends. I am using Google Chrome v28 for this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you attaching the listener after the DOM is created? For example, if you log the result of just `document.getElementById('myplayer')`, is it `null`?

Comment: Yes, I am adding the listener after the DOM is created. I don't see any errors in the Resources view of the HTML.

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/fFS9p/1/. Also, an error would appear in your *console* ("*TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null*"), not your Resources panel. But if there's no error there either, it may simply be an issue related to playing certain media codecs or particular files.

Comment: There was no error of null. As when in the chrome console I typed the values the results were correct. But when I wrote the event listener in windows.onload function it started working fine. Thank You very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756251/cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null-error)